# Horizontal overflow mobile

Tags: mobile

I've been looking for hours now but can't seem to find the problem to why I have an horizontal scrollbar on mobile screen.

If you need any code, I'd be happy to paste it here but I don't even know what code is necessary.

http://sap.clouddesign.be/public/

Comment: If you are not providing any code, then at least leave the link in place … or just delete the whole question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.row` element in `#subfooter` has a `margin-right:-15px` coming from bootstrap.

Normally this is countered by the 15px horizontal padding of the `.container` element around `.rows` – but that is missing in this case.

Either put a `.container` element around the `.row`, or eliminate that `margin-right` for that specific element, and the scrollbar will be gone.

Comment: There is already a `.container` around `.row`, plus eliminating `margin-right` doesn't fix it.

Comment: _“There is already a `.container` around `.row`”_ – yes, but for that one you explicitly eliminated the `padding-right` via a rule with selector `#footer #subfooter` in your own stylesheet … _“plus eliminating `margin-right` doesn't fix it”_ – it does for me, at least in Responsive Design View in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have some div error i think. You can fix this really easy. Just you need to do add   overflow-x: hidden; for body element.